# this is undefined while trying to inherit prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am trying to add prototype dynamically but for some reason this keyword return `undefined` when I try to inherit `prototype`. But when I run same code on browser console it works fine. Why its not working with Node.js?

I have also included my full code at the end of question.

My main issue happens here:

```
let postObj = function(){
  this.data = post;
  this.originalIndex = i;
};

//postObj.prototype = postProto; // have same result
postObj.prototype = Object.create(postProto);

//postObj.data = post;
_self.posts.push(new postObj());
```

When I try to access `this` inside prototype method it always return undefined. for example `postProto` has a method `id` which looks for `this.data._id`. As you can see I have already set constructors for `postObj`, then why this is not being passed to prototype?

Please tell me whats wrong here.

**full code:**

```
const postPrototype = {
  id: (){
    return this.data._id;
  },

  title: (){
    return this.data.title;
  }
}

function fetchPosts(){
  this.posts = [];

  this.rawPosts = [
    {_id: '1', title: 'In sit amet lorem velit, in dictum lorem'},
    {_id: '2', title: 'Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibu'},
    {_id: '3', title: 'Integer vulputate nibh et diam sagittis in dictum mauris dapibus'}
  ];

  this.inheritPrototype();
}

fetchPosts.prototype.inheritPrototype = function(){
  var _self = this;

  if(!_.isEmpty(_self.rawPosts)){
    _self.rawPosts.forEach(function(post, i){
      try{
        let postObj = function(){
          this.data = post;
          this.originalIndex = i;
        };

        //postObj.prototype = postProto; // have same result
        postObj.prototype = Object.create(postPrototype);

        //postObj.data = post;
        _self.posts.push(new postObj());

      }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  }

};

fetchPosts.prototype.get = function(){
  return this.posts;
}


var sampleFetch = new fetchPosts();
sampleFetch.get().forEach(function(post, i){
  post.id(); // This return error: cannot get property _id undefined
});
```

Comment: `postPrototype` would need a `data` Object for starters.

Comment: @PHPglue you mean a empty data object in `postPrototype` ? Thanks

Comment: This code is absolutely ridiculous. It all needs to be redone. Is this a school assignment? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Indeed it is. I am just trying to learn Node.js

Comment: I am trying to apply prototype for existing object in collections

Answer (score 0):

First of all, because of try catch block you hided error which is: `"ReferenceError: postProto is not defined"`. At the top of your script, you have defined `postPrototype` variable but you used `postProto` which is of course undefined.

Also, in declaration of `postPrototype` you have used object literal shorthand but not properly. You should use it without `:`.

```
const postPrototype = {
  id (){
    return this.data._id;
  },

  title (){
    return this.data.title;
  }
}
```

I have edited your code [here](https://jsbin.com/xihaqozowu/edit?js,console).

Comment: Sorry, that was typo error while writing question. I updated question.

Comment: It would be like `id: function(){}`, in an Object Literal.

Comment: In ES 5 yes, but in ES6 you can ommit `:` and `function` keyword in object declaration.

Comment: @PawełMikołajczyk but I think it can be done only with class ?

Comment: No, you can use it also in object literals.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.

Comment: I edited my anwser and added your code edited which works.